# what are some of the best resources to learn advanced debugging techniques using gdb?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I know the basics of how to use gdb. But I would like to learn some advanced debugging techniques using gdb. What are the best resources - books, blogs, tutorials - that any of you use regularly. I did look at this question: [Tips or resources for learning advanced debugging techniques GDB in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151808/tips-or-resources-for-learning-advanced-debugging-techniques-gdb-in-xcode) but what I'm looking for is the GDB equivalent of the following:

http://www.dumpanalysis.org/

http://WinDbg.info

[Memory Dump Analysis Anthology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0955832802)

I understand that this is subjective question. But there are lot of questions which are very similar in nature (e.g [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)) and this question is not asked in here. If there is a duplicate that I missed please site it in the comments and close this question.

Comment: The aim of the question is to merely collect some of the resources that other developers have used and found it to be very useful. I did my due research on the internet and couldn't find anything that stood out like the examples I have cited with regards to WinDBG. The question does not solicit opinions.

Comment: If you want to learn `gdb` specifics, [Debugging with GDB](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html) linked in the SO answer is a good place to go. If you want to learn advanced debugging techniques, it's usually more about general computer and OS architecture knowledge than about anything else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Norman Matloff's book on debugging: [The Art of Debugging](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271743) is quite good, though I don't know if you would consider it advanced. There is also his online tutorial, [Guide to Faster, Less Frustrating Debugging](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/CLanguage/Debug.html), which might be an earlier version of the book.

There is also a tutorial [My debugging tutorial](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Debug/Debug.pdf), linked from the page [Norm Matloff's DDD Tutorial](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/ddd.html).

Personally, I use print statements. :-)
I've tried to use GDB in the past, but only with C++ (I don't use C). The problems I had were that, first GDB was itself quite buggy, and second, did not cope well with displaying complex C++ structures. This was some time ago, and the situation may have improved.

Comment: +1 for the Guide to Faster, lesser frustrating debugging link.